# SSH Auth Failed on Amazon EC2 - RSEG1066 Auth Failed

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, rsa, pem, eclipse-rse

Sorry but I am a newbie...  I have checked other questions but nothing has worked and I am not great with SSH.

Followed the steps to [connect to EC2 with SSH in Eclipse](http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/ssh-to-amazon-aws-with-eclipse-remote-system-explorer-rse/).  Worked like a charm.  Then I terminated the working server and started a new instance.

Now I can't connect and receive
`RSEG1066 "Failed to connect sshd on server name" Auth failed`

Also Port 22 is open ->
`Port 22 (SSH) Source: 0.0.0.0/0`

My SSH connection references the new hostname and I have applied my .pem file via rsa.  Any thoughts?  What else should I check?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems many people are having this [problem with AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=90451) when terminating an instance and launching a new instance.  Here is what I did to solve the problem for me.

1. Terminated instance
2. Deleted key pair from AWS console
3. Deleted key pair from client
4. Launched a new instance
5. When prompted, used a different name for my key pair (.pem) file
6. Choose the default security group
7. Added SSH / Port 22 inbound access to the security group
8. Connected (with user *ubuntu* since I am using an ubunutu server)

And if using Eclipse RSE like the tutorial link in the original question, be sure to restart Eclipse before connecting.